# Twitter API doesn't return search results even though they exist

Tags: python, twitter

Im trying to get all of a user's tweets for a 2 month time period. In search I see results but this code returns an empty array. Why?

```
results = api.GetSearch(raw_query="q=&from=yikyakapp&since=2014-09-24&until=2014-11-24")

    print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Twitter search API has a limit of 7 days. Check the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.

There is a detailed explanation here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

> Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words,
>   no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

In summary, you can't use Twitter API to search for tweets beyond 7 days. Of course, in the website they can show you whatever they want. They hold all the data.

Comment: I just tweeted 10 minutes ago and it's not in the search result.

Comment: @siddiq: Perhaps you should have gone through the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) before downvoting.  *"Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface."* In either case, I don't maintain Twitter API myself!